# Why is wtxid called "hash" in Bitcoin Core's getrawtransaction RPC?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, hash, transaction-id, getrawtransaction

In the industry txid is known as "transaction hash". Why wasn't the "hash" field called "wtxid"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that it is returning the hash of the entire transaction data. Currently, that is always identical to the wtxid.

But in a hypothetical future, where more data may get added to transaction serializations, in addition to the base data (covered by txid) and witness data, hash would change to always cover everything.